# After calling focus on a given element the selection range's getClientRects will return an empty list

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using the following code to select the element

```
const selectEnd = (element: HTMLElement, position: number) => {
  element.focus();
  
  const range = document.createRange();
  const sel = window.getSelection();

  if (position !== -1) {
    range.setStart(element, Math.min(position, element.childNodes.length));
  } else {
    range.setStart(element, element.childNodes.length);
  }

  sel?.removeAllRanges();
  sel?.addRange(range);
};
```

After selecting the element the following rect variable will always be undefined

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();

if (!selection) return;

const range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
range.collapse(true);

const rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
```

But after an onInput event happens on the client the range.getClientRects function will return a value.

I'm trying to get range.getClientRects() to return a variable after the focus call without the user needing to input anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You felt on [CSSWG#2514](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2514).

The problem is that browsers aren't able to calculate the `DOMRects` composing a collapsed `Range` which is anchored to an `Element` (instead of a `Node`).

This [CKEditor issue](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/issues/1930) lists a few cases where this can happen, along with a few potential workarounds.

**1. A collapsed `Range` in an `Element` that does have content. (Most probably your case)**

Setting the `Range` on the closest `TextNode` would allow the browsers to calculate the boxes correctly:

```js
const el = document.querySelector("div");
const range = new Range();
// to show the "bug"
range.selectNode(el);
range.collapse(true);
console.log("selecting the Element", range.getClientRects().length); // 0

// the workaround
range.setStart(el.firstChild, 0);
range.collapse(true);
console.log("selecting the Node", range.getClientRects().length); // 1
```

```html
<div>target</div>
```

Though i's also possible that the element's `firstChild` isn't a `TextNode` either, so you actually need a method to retrieve the first `TextNode` in that `Element`:

```js
function getFirstTextNode(target) {
  return document.createNodeIterator(target, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT).nextNode();  
}
const el = document.querySelector("div");
const range = new Range();
// to show how our previous version fails
range.setStart(el.firstChild, 0);
range.collapse(true);
console.log("selecting the firstChild", range.getClientRects().length); // 0

// the workaround
const firstNode = getFirstTextNode(el);
range.setStart(firstNode, 0);
range.collapse(true);
console.log("selecting the first TextNode", range.getClientRects().length); // 1
```

```html
<div><span></span>target</div>
```

**2. A `Range` in an empty `Element`, (and thus without `TextNode` to select)**

For this one you can try appending a Zero-Width-Space (ZWSP) character inside the `Element`, take your measure on the newly created `TextNode`, remove the character.

```js
function getFirstTextNode(target) {
  return document.createNodeIterator(target, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT).nextNode();  
}
const el = document.querySelector("div");
const range = new Range();
let firstTextNode = getFirstTextNode(el);
const wasEmpty = !firstTextNode;

if (wasEmpty) {
  console.log("inserting a ZWSP");
  firstTextNode = new Text("\u200B");
  el.append(firstTextNode);
}
range.setStart(firstTextNode, 0);
range.collapse(true);
const rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
if (wasEmpty) {
  firstTextNode.remove();
}
console.log(rect); // DOMRect
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**3. A `Range` that sits in-between two elements**

```html
...</div>|<div>...
```

Here again you can use the ZWSP trick. Detecting this might become a bit more terse though, and given OP apparently wants to set the caret at the beginning of the `Element`, that doesn't seem like a possibility for them. So I'll leave the example off from this answer.